# Masking of Headers and Properties in SAP CPI

Tags: groovy, header, data-masking, sap-cpi

We developed an iflow in SAP CPI which gets user credentials from Secure store service and use them to get the access token which will be used to get the required data. The problem here is the credentials are being visible in properties . How can I mask these headers and properties using groovy. They should be seen as****** only